Hide inherited getters on hover in VS Code (node)
Let's take the following example: we create a chain of objects A > B > C by defining getters in A and B. When we hover over C in debug mode, the inherited getters are displayed at the same level as C's own properties.

Is it possible to configure VS code to hide inherited getters on hover?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@Reyno The question is specifically about the VSCode GUI. It's not clear how to ask about this without showing it as a screenshot.

But the OP should post the code as text in addition to the screenshot that shows the hover effect in question.
